# jQuery UI datepicker - How to use dateFormat for dates inside the code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I want to manipulate with some dates in my datepicker calendar, I just don't know how can I write the dates in the date format that I want. When I use `dateFormat` in my code it won't work.

My answer probably lies here somewhere but I can't figure it out where to use it in my code.
http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat

My code:

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function(){
  var sesa1 = new Date(2019, 05, 04); // I want to write this dates in dd-mm-yy format
  var sesa2 = new Date(2019, 06, 06); // They curently work in yy-mm-dd format 
 $(".picker").datepicker({
//dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' , // If I uncoment this line the defaultDate will go in year 2024!
    defaultDate: '05/07/2019', // It works in format mm-dd-yy and I want it to be in dd-mm-yy
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            var day = date.getDay();
            if (date >= sesa1 && date <= sesa2) {
                return [(day != 0 && day != 1 ) ? true : false, 'green', 'some text'];
            }
            return [true, "", "sometext"]; 
        }

  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **defaultDate**
>
> Set the date to highlight on first opening if the field is blank. Specify either an actual date via a Date object or as a string in the current `dateFormat`, or a number of days from today (e.g. +7) or a string of values and periods ('y' for years, 'm' for months, 'w' for weeks, 'd' for days, e.g. '+1m +7d'), or null for today.

Since your default date is not presented in the proper format, it is not read right.

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $(function(){
    var sesa1 = new Date(2019, 05, 04);
    var sesa2 = new Date(2019, 06, 06); 
    $(".picker").datepicker({
      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
      defaultDate: '07-05-2019',
      beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var day = date.getDay();
        if (date >= sesa1 && date <= sesa2) {
          return [(day != 0 && day != 1 ) ? true : false, 'green', 'some text'];
        }
        return [true, "", "sometext"]; 
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Also if you need to make a `Date` from a string, try using `$.datepicker.parseDate()`.

> **$.datepicker.parseDate( format, value, options )**
>
> Extract a date from a string value with a specified format.

This way, if you can have date strings that are different formats, you can get a Date object regardless. To reverse it, use `$.datepicker.formatDate( format, date, options )`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I think I understand what will `parseDate` do but the problem is that I'm new to  javascript and I don't know where to properly put  and edit `$.datepicker.parseDate( format, value, options )` in my code. If you could show me or point me to some guide I would really appreciate it, cause currently all my tries to use it have failed.

Comment: Use it to assign the resulting date object into a variable.